# multiple vue js instances vs components , ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, bootstrap-tabs

I want to render ajax tabs using vue js. For each tab, ajax request fetches template + data from api.

so these are the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" ajax-url="/tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" ajax-url="/tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" ajax-url="/tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
   var url = event.target.getAttribute("ajax-url");
   // fetch template and data..
   // init vue instance for the new tab
})
</script>
```

How should I integrate vue into this? Separate vue instances for each tab, or components? I also need support for preloading some of the tabs.
Since I need to initialize the vue instances on demand, I'm not sure what is the good way to manage that. For angular, I would define ng-controller for each tab. But in vue.js it seems there isn't one correct project architecture.

Answer (score 3):

For the tabs, use `vue-router`

Each route will load a separate View/Component when active. However, this is preloaded as the vue.js bundle file contains all the code required to render.

The `Vue Lifecycle hooks`, such as `created` and `mounted` are commonly used to perform setup or fetching of additional data in each View.

It looks like your example is homogenous enough that a single vue instance can handle all the workings (no jQuery/AJAX required).

If your use-cases differ greatly sometimes it is more effective to build multiple separate components, each compiled into their own JS file (usually done with Webpack's multiple '`entry`' setting).

**UPDATE**

There is a way to bundle Vue components using the CLI see: [Compile .vue file into .js file without webpack or browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780134/compile-vue-file-into-js-file-without-webpack-or-browserify)

Note that each Component will be able to mount a separate tab, using `el` attribute which works similar to the Angular 'ng-controller' directive:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#tab1',
  data () {
    return {
      obj
    }
  }
})
```

However, I think what you're trying to do is to control Vue instances from outside of Vue (ie: using jQuery). This is probably not recommended.

If you decide to go with Webpack, you are still able to use Bootstrap. The are various ways to integrate Bootstrap, personally i would recommend importing the SCSS. However your mileage may vary. But don't be put off, there are plenty of online resources to keep you going.

Comment: Do I have to use a component for each tab? For this project I can't use webpack or other builders. I prefer to integrate vue.js incrementally, so I can't ditch jQuery yet.  I need jQuery for bootstrap. What I want is to load a template + data for each tab. vue-router looks somewhat complicated and most of the docs assume that I use webpack/bundler

Comment: See my update for the answer to this question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: the CLI is also not an option for me, as I've said I don't use a builder like webpack and that include vue cli. Tried the vue router but it seems too overloaded for my purpose (I don't need hashbangs, links state management, just load ajax tab on click).  I tried to define my tabs on JS code like vue router does, and then use v-for on the <li> elements. But is there any way to define the tabs in HTML like bootstrap requires?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use seperate Vue instances in case you don't want the `vue-router`..
but it will cause some memory leaks some issues so to some this .. 
when ever you will make an ajax request when a tab is clicked you have to first destroy the current Vue instance.. then add the data to the dom

```
 let app =  new Vue({
            el:  '#app',

        })
// doo other stuff
    $.ajax({
      // ajax settings
      success: function(data){
       // here you should destroy the Old Vue instance otherwise it will make issues
        app.$destroy()
        $('body').html(data);
      }
    })
```

I would suggest you to make a small javascript plugin..
when a link is clicked it will take the url of the link perform an ajax request and serve the data to the page on every request it will fire a callback .. where you destory the old new Instance..
and for some kind of loader you can use another call back before ajax request to show the page loader or something..

I have used this technique in one of my project.. i'hv made a plugin with jquery ajax...
here it is...

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
import anime from 'animejs';
export let Loader = (function(window , document , undefined){

    class Loader{

        constructor(options = null){
            this.options = Object.assign({ pageProgressBar : false , pageProgressBarDuraion: 2000 } , options);
            this.functions = [];
            this.xhr = null;
            this.routes = this.options.routes || [];

            window.addEventListener('load' , this.init.bind(this));
        }        
        init(){

            if(this.options.container)
                this.$container = $(this.options.container).length ? $(this.options.container) : $(document.body)
            else            
                this.$container = $(document.body)    


            this.functions['popstate'] =  this.onPopState.bind(this);
            window.addEventListener('popstate' , this.functions['popstate'] );

            this.functions['handleLinks'] = this.handleLinks.bind(this);
            window.addEventListener('click' , this.functions['handleLinks']);
        }
        pushHistory(type , url){
            var state = {url : url , type : type};
            window.history.pushState(state , '' , url);
        }
        onPopState(e){
            var state = e.state;

            if(state == null)
                return true;

            this.loadUrl(state.url)
        }
        handleLinks(e){
            if(!e.target.matches('[ajax-link]'))
                return ;
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = e.target.href;
            var self = this;

            this.loadUrl(url).then(function(){            
                self.pushHistory('get' , url);
            });
        }

        load(url)
        {
            let self = this;
            return new Promise(function(resolve , reject){
                self.loadUrl(url).then(function(){

                    self.pushHistory('get' , url);
                    resolve();
                });    
            });
        }


        loadUrl(url){
            var isError = true;
            if(this.xhr)
            {
                isError = false;
                if(this.options.onAbort)
                    this.options.onAbort();
                this.xhr.abort();
                if(this.options.pageProgressBar)
                    restartProgressBar();
                this.xhr = null;
            }

            var route = this.getMatchingRoute(url);
            if(route)
            {
                if(route.beforeLoad)
                    route.beforeLoad();
            }

            if(this.beforeLoading)
                this.beforeLoading();


            var self = this;
            return new Promise(function(resolve , reject){
               self.xhr = $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: 'get',
                    cache : false,
                    beforeSend (xhr){

                        if(self.options.onLoading)
                            self.options.onLoading(xhr);

                        if(self.options.pageProgressBar)
                            startProgressBar( self.options.pageProgressBarDuration );
                    },
                    success (data){

                        self.$container.html(data);
                        self.xhr = null;
                        resolve();

                        if(route && route.afterLoad)
                            route.afterLoad();

                        if(self.options.onLoaded)
                            self.options.onLoaded(data);
                        if(self.options.pageProgressBar)
                            endProgressBar();
                    },
                    error (response){
                        if(response.response)
                            window.location = url;
                    },
                });
            });
        }
        reload(){
            this.loadUrl(window.location.href);
        }
        getMatchingRoute(url){
            if(this.routes)
            {   
                for(let i = 0; i< this.routes.length ; i++)
                {
                    var route = this.routes[i];
                    if(url.indexOf(route.route) >= 0 ){
                        return route;
                    }
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
        destory(){
            window.removeEventListener('popstate' , this.functions['popstate'] );
        }
    }
    return Loader;



    // Provate progressbar methods
    var $pageProgressBar = null;

    function restartProgressBar(){
        $pageProgressBar.remove();
        anime.remove($pageProgressBar[0]);
    }
    function startProgressBar( duration = 3000){
        $pageProgressBar = $('<div>').addClass('page-progressbar')
        $('body').append($pageProgressBar)

        anime({
            targets: $pageProgressBar[0],
            width: '70%',
            easing : 'easeInOutQuad',
            duration : 3000
        });
    }
    function endProgressBar(){
        anime.remove($pageProgressBar[0]);
        var $prog = $('.page-progressbar');
        $prog.css({ width: '100%' , transition :".35s all" , 'webkit-transition' : ".35s all" });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            $prog.css({ opacity: '0'});
            setTimeout( () => $pageProgressBar[0].remove() , 200);
        },350);
    }


}(window , document , undefined));
```

it has some progress bars and other things you can remove that modify it
now all you have to do is

```
window.Loader = new Loader({
// tell it the tag you want to put data in 
container :"#app-data",
})
```

then add the `ajax-link` attribute to any link in your case its tabs links
it will pull the url and put the contents to the container you specfied
and there are some call backs
you can add a `Loader.beforeLoading = function(){
            app.$destroy();
        }`
and thats it