# How to use a VueJS .vue component in a HTML page without a WebPack build process?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a page for a legacy server rendered project.

On one of its page I need to add some "dynamic". Then i import the vuejs CDN script and created a inline vue object

```
var v = new Vue(...
```

But there is a [.vue component](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-switches) that I like very much and I would like to add it to the page. But it seems that this component can only be added by a WebPack import and build process.

How can I use this component in my html page without WebPack build process? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [poi](https://poi.js.org) as described in [this article](https://medium.com/poi-js/bundle-and-publish-your-vue-componet-like-a-pro-9ce27f9b5f65):

```
poi build Component.vue --format cjs
```

You can also use [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) 3 (beta) and the necessary global addon:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global
# or
yarn global add @vue/cli
yarn global add @vue/cli-service-global

vue build Component.vue
```

Use `vue build --help` to get options and the help text.
But be aware that this generates production minified code with an app and vendor bundle (which includes vue).

See also [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787068/1363486) to a similar question, mentioning the use of the previous [build](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/docs/build.md) command in `vue-cli` 2.8.x

Comment: i tried the first option but. `We are slimming down vue-cli to optimize the initial installation by removing the `vue build` command.`

Comment: well, you could try an older version of vue-cli (2.8.x) just to compile this, or use one of the other options

Comment: vue-component-compiler was depreciated and merged into vuefy