# How do I use other vuejs component directly in my static HTML?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am newbee at vuejs.
I have a website and i want to use vuejs in some page.
The page is built by laravel, jquery etc. and I want to use vuejs draggable component at particular area in that page.

https://kutlugsahin.github.io/vue-smooth-dnd

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Everyone said that Vuejs is good to easily start at running services. But not for me.
I want to use above vue component in my existing HTML page without a WebPack build process.

That means, i will use only

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

and just plain html and js. (if possible, not use import things)

I read the article [How to use a VueJS .vue component in a HTML page without a WebPack build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906031/how-to-use-a-vuejs-vue-component-in-a-html-page-without-a-webpack-build-process),

They said "poi" is the best solution.
At last of the answer, they said that i have to use ["import Component from ..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhnuU.png).

I cant not use "import" at my current plain html page. (cause i do not use webpack etc)

Is there someone to tell me real solution easily?

Comment: The `apache-poi` you have tagged has nothing to do with the "poi" mentioned in your links.

Comment: Sorry, i deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **do not use** Webpack then you can just include the .js files into your HTML page - either use CDN or local files (you can get them by entering bellow links and save as..):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.7.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.16.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>
```

Quick example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      list: ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']
    };
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.drag-container {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.drag-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.7.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.16.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Dragable Test</h1>

  <draggable :list="list" class="drag-container">
    <div v-for="item in list" class="drag-item">{{ item }}</div>
  </draggable>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I found that even if it's late the official way is the best way. For all people read this article, I recommend reading the official site 10 times.

Comment: If you share the complete code samples it will be helpful for those who starts Vue new. I meant complete HTML file.

Comment: The important part not-to-forget is to include sortable.js as well. I cannot find that in the documentation anywhere.